# Connecting multiple keyboards in iOS 14 Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios14

`iOS 14` introduced `GCKeyboard`. I was able to successfully connect a `BlueTooth NumberPad` in my app but I need to be able to connect two of them in tandem. Could anyone please point me to sample code?

In the `GCController` class there is a "`controllers`" method which returns an array of all connected controllers, but there isn't anything similar for `GCKeyboard`.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];

    // notifications for keyboard (dis)connect
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWasConnected:) name:GCKeyboardDidConnectNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWasDisconnected:) name:GCKeyboardDidDisconnectNotification object:nil];
}

GCKeyboard *leftKeyboard;
GCKeyboard *rightKeyboard;

- (void)keyboardWasConnected:(NSNotification *)notification {
    
    if (!self.leftKeyboard) {
        leftKeyboard = (GCKeyboard *)notification.object;
        NSLog(@"Left Keyboard connected: %@\n", leftKeyboard.description);
        NSString *keyboardStatus = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Left Keyboard CONNECTED:\n%@", leftKeyboard.description];
        self.statusLabel.text = keyboardStatus;
        
        self.leftKeyboard = leftKeyboard;
        [self reactToKeyboardInput];
    }
    else if (!self.rightKeyboard) {
        NSLog(@"Right Keyboard connected: %@\n", rightKeyboard.description);
        rightKeyboard = (GCKeyboard *)notification.object;
        NSString *keyboardStatus = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Right Keyboard CONNECTED:\n%@", rightKeyboard.description];
        self.statusLabel.text = keyboardStatus;
        
        self.rightKeyboard = rightKeyboard;
        [self reactToKeyboardInput];
    }
}

- (void)keyboardWasDisconnected:(NSNotification *)notification {
    
    if (self.leftKeyboard) {
        GCKeyboard *keyboard = (GCKeyboard *)notification.object;
        NSString *status = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Left Keyboard DISCONNECTED:\n%@", keyboard.description];
        self.statusLabel.text = status;
    
        self.leftKeyboard = nil;
    }
    else if (self.rightKeyboard) {
        GCKeyboard *keyboard = (GCKeyboard *)notification.object;
        NSString *status = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Right Keyboard DISCONNECTED:\n%@", keyboard.description];
        self.statusLabel.text = status;
    
        self.rightKeyboard = nil;
    }
}
```

When a keyboard or number pad is connected I get the message:

```
2020-09-18 13:09:15.845943-0700 Controller[1653:351628] Left Keyboard connected: GCController 0x280bb8dd0 ('Keyboard' - 0x27c3dc28cec4d818)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Bring keyboard and mouse gaming to iPad" WWDC video transcript states:

> In the case of keyboards, you can't differentiate multiple keyboards, and all keyboard events from multiple keyboards are instead coalesced for you. So while you might use notifications to notice when a keyboard disconnects and perhaps pause the game to prompt for different input, in general, you'll find that just using GCKeyboard-Device.coalesced to check on the key state when non-nil is the right path.

So while you may have multiple keyboards connected, it sounds like they all get coalesced into a single `GCKeyboard` instance and you can't differentiate between them. That is why there's no `+[GCKeyboard keyboards]` method. Instead there is `+[GCKeyboard coalescedKeyboard]`

Comment: Thank you Zorg. Unfortunately the same is true for mouse as well. There is no way to differentiate if more than one Bluetooth mouse is paired. The weird thing is that a GCKeyboard is somehow associated with GCController as can be seen in the GCKeyboard.description property "GCController 0x280bb8dd0 ('Keyboard' - 0x27c3dc28cec4d818)" And For GCController there is a playerIndex property, which can be set to say GCControllerPlayerIndex1. I wonder if GCKeyboard can be somehow cast to GCController so I can use this property. Any Suggestions?

Comment: Mice are not coalesced according to the documentation. You should be able to differentiate between multiple mice, through the notification handlers or `+[GCMouse mice]`. GCKeyboard and GCController are both part of same framework and conform to `GCDevice` protocol. Their input properties are subclasses of `GCPhysicalInputProfile`. GCKeyboard doesn't have playerIndex property because it doesn't make much sense - there's no such LED indicator on the keyboard to show the player index.

Comment: Thank you for pointing [GCMouse mice] out, @Zorg. I tried it and it works fine for distinguishing multiple paired mice as documented. As for the [GCKeyboard coalescedKeyboard], I wonder if there is a way to get access to the GCContoller.framework source code so I can modify GCKeyboard and add the "keyboards" property and recompile it locally. I know that in most cases distinguishing between keyboards does not make much sense, but it makes perfect sense for my app:-) Does Apple make such sources publicly available? If so, where can I download them from?

Comment: No, that's quite wishful thinking. You also can't use private APIs if you want to be approved for App Store. You can check UIKit's APIs for handling physical keyboards (I've no familiarity there) if it allows to differentiate them. There's a decent chance GCKeyboard is coalesced because of else in the iOS stack.